# Have to to enter full search term otherwise no results are shown

Tags: 2013, 2010, search, search-results, search-scope

In my list there is a column called DUC number with entries like:

DUC-1000-100
DUC-1001-101
DUC-1000-102

On SP 2010 if I search `1000-100` then it brings search result. But on SP 2013 I had to write it fully like `DUC-1000-100` otherwise it doesn't bring any search result.

How do I make 2013 search like 2010 one?

Comment: I would expect that to work as I thought (possibly incorrectly) that a hyphen is a break word. I assume this is set as searchable managed property?

Comment: That 2010 one is SharePoint Foundation 2010. Do you think it is working in 2010 because of Foundation version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply searching without hyphen brings result. For e.g. `DUC 1000 102` instead of `DUC-1000-102`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize ranking model in SP13, you can give the DUC number property more weight. First way is to [change it's weight group in the search schema](http://www.techmikael.com/2015/01/how-to-boost-metadata-in-sharepoint.html)

Otherwise you can modify the search query: Sorting > Dynamic ordering > Add dynamic ordering rule. You can promote the search results that contains a specific managed property.

Comment: That 2010 one is SharePoint Foundation 2010. Do you think it is working in 2010 because of Foundation version?